# Running bash script from crontab

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron, notify-send

I am having difficulty running the below simple script from crontab:

```
#!/bin/bash
notify-send "battery.sh working"
```

The permissions of the file are `rwxr-xr-x` and its running fine with either of the commands `bash battery.sh` and `sh battery.sh`.

In my crontab, I have tried running it with both `bash` and `sh`, with absolute as well as local path. My current crontab looks as follows:

```
* * * * * /home/marpangal/battery.sh
* * * * * sh battery.sh
* * * * * bash battery.sh
* * * * * sh /home/marpangal/battery.sh
* * * * * bash /home/marpangal/battery.sh
```

However the cron does not execute the script and I get no message from notify-send.

Comment: Have you tried just adding the path to the file? like so: `* * * * * /home/marpangal/battery.sh`. Also, is your crontab running as your user? Because the group does not have the execute permission o the file.

Comment: I added the path to the file like `* * * * * /home/marpangal/battery.sh`. I have also provided the execute permissions to all. But still I am not getting any message from notify-send. I am adding the cron with `crontab -e` .

Comment: It's most likely that `notify-send` isn't in the minimal `PATH` that cron uses -- see [superuser: "crontab and binaries in /usr/local/bin"](https://superuser.com/questions/784252/crontab-and-binaries-in-usr-local-bin) and [askubuntu: "Why crontab scripts are not working?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working) for details and other common problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notify-send` needs the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable in order to communicate with the current desktop session. Since `cron` runs with an almost empty environment, this variable is not available.

But you can set it directly in your `battery.sh` script:

```
export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)
notify-send "Message from cron"
```

This looks up the process id of your `gnome-session` and extracts the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` (along with its value) from then `gnome-sessions`' environment.

Now `notify-send` is able to display notifications in your desktop session.

Answer (score 0):

Flopps’s answer gives me a `-bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input` – so i tried something different:

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus
notify-send "Message from cron"
```

i assume this is not as flexible as the original export but it works for me in my user crontab.